# What would the effects be of a world where darkness took precedence over light?

Tags: society, culture, light

Just yesterday I was thinking about how light takes precedence over darkness.  What I mean by this is that a small light still shines through a large darkness; **darkness is defined as the absence of light**.  And I thought, Wouldn't it be really cool if there were a world where it was the other way around?  If **light was defined as the absence of darkness?**

My thoughts are that there is naturally light, but dark-sources (like uncandles or non-lamps) cause darkness to shine through the light.  Or something.

How would that work and how would it affect human culture and evolution?

Comment: Do you mean, like, there is a dark "sun", and when it isn't shining you can see the white brightness that is earth's "shadow"? And I don't mean it figuratively.

Comment: Everything is, by default, in light just like the default is dark in our world; stars and other stuff like that give off darkness, which shines through the light.  Imagine a candle giving off light.  It's really bright up close, but dims as you get farther away.  I don't know what it would look like, but in this world it is the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Light and Dark are subjective literally in the eye of the beholder.

Let's say there was a planet where life evolved in such a way that their vision is active, based some sort of beam bounced they off things and read by the eyes. For some reason, this beam was interfered with by photons making a society that could see in shadows but not in light.

They would not have much use for light bulbs  torches etc except as a way to darken a room for a nap or for a way to hide. So they would not have a rush to invent such things. Their buildings would have windows for looking out but not for letting light in. They would use fire for cooking but would prefer a low coal to a burner.

They would, of course, be nocturnal as the big dumb sky darkener skin burner would not be much help for getting about The night sky would be a near black brassy dome with black clouds . The Day sky would have The lesser darkener in the day that reflects the darkness would also be a bother. Both would be worshiped as demons and Gods. The sky in their day would be speckled with black dots as pictured here. [image: inverted sky] They would be very good at astronomy seeing the stars throughout the day.

In their religion and other poetry, Dark and Hot would be linked terms. Their Churches and temples would either be dark tight and brilliantly bright or have latticed ceilings to light streams of darkness in depending on the orientation of the faith.

sunsets would be terrifying 
[image: inverted sunset in color]

Comment: But what if we still liked light, just it folded to darkness?  That's what I'm getting at.

Comment: @CHEESE then you need to edit the question to incorporate that idea.

Answer (score 0):

THE THEORY OF DARK SUCKERS

as presented by Paul Holmgren

with additions and corrections by Holly Stowe

For years it was believed that light wes emitted from an electric bulb; recent information has proven otherwise - dark is sucked into the bulb - therefore, the bulb is a dark sucker.

There are many types and sizes of dark suckers. The largest manufacturers of dark suckers are General Electric and Sylvania. Some modern dark suckers utilize solid power to operate properly. Solid power units can be purchased from Eveready, Exide, and Duracell.

The dark sucker theory proves the existance of dark suckers as well as proving that dark is heaver than light. Some examples are as follows:
Electric bulbs: There is less dark near the electric bulb than at a distance of 100 feet when it is operating; therefore, it is sucking dark and can be classified as a dark sucker. The larger the dark sucker, the greater the distance it can suck dark. The larger the dark sucker the greater its capacity of dark. The dark sucking capabilities are evident when the dark sucker has reached its capacity and will no longer suck dark. At that point you may notice the dark area on the inside portion of the dark sucker. The larger the dark sucker, the larger the area of dark found within. This type of dark sucker can be made directional by placing a shield around a portion of the unit or behind it. This will prevent dark from entering the dark sucker from that side thereby extending the range of the dark sucker on the unprotected/unshielded side.
Candles - primitive dark suckers: There is more dark 30 feet from a lit candle then there is at a distance of 3 feet. Proof of it's dark sucking capabilities is relatively simple. Examine a new unused candle, notice that the center core is not dark. Ignite the center core. Allow the center core to burn for about 5 minutes. Notice the lack of dark around the candle. Extinguish the candle flame. Notice that the center core of the candle is now dark. The center core is a dark sucker protected by a soft insulator to extend it's life expectancy and maintain rigidity to verify that this primitive dark sucker is operating properly. Ignite the center core and allow it to burn for a minimum of 2 minutes. Pass a clean pencil over the top of the flame, left to right, approximately 3 inches above the center core. Notice that there is no dark on the pencil. Pass the pencil over the center core now about 1/2 inch. Notice that the pencil now has a dark area. The pencil blocked the path of the dark being sucked to the core of the dark sucker. This type dark sucker is very primitive and does not suck dark any great distance nor does it have a large capacity.

Dark sucker solid power units may be purchased locally at a variety of outlets. Size does not determine the life expectancy of the dark sucker solid power unit. These solid power units work with many modern dark suckers, and absorb dark from the dark sucker. The absorbed dark is converted to solid power within the unit.

An example of the conversion of dark into solid power in the automobile of today. Notice an auto in use during dark hours. Two (possibly four) large dark suckers are located on the front. On the rear there are two (or 3) smaller dark suckers with red filters. You may also notice several dark suckers with yellow filters. These filters are required to remove a percentage of red and yellow from total dark so as to energize the solid power unit. The solid power unit permits the auto to be utilized during hours of no dark by the dark it has absorbed. The number of dark suckers varies with the age of the automobile. Newer automobile solid power units require a greater percentage of red filtered dark. Older units generally require more non-filtered dark. The solid power unit of the automobile has a dark interior. This can be proved by cutting the solid power unit in half.

Dark is heavier than light. Dark always settles to the bottom of a lake and/or river. Submerge just below the surface of a lake and you will notice an absence of dark. Lower yourself to 15 feet below the surface and you will notice a degree of darkness even on a sunny, bright day. Lower yourself to 50 feet (or more) below the surface and you are in total dark. Ergo, the dark has settled to the bottom; therefore, dark is heavier than light. Modern technology has allowed us to utilize the dark that has settled to the bottom of large rivers through the creation of turbines which push the dark downriver to the ocean, which has a larger holding capacity for dark and is a common safe storage location. As the dark is passed through the turbine, a percentage of solid power is removed and transmitted to various short term storage plants for many usages. Prior to turbines, it was much more difficult to move the dark from rivers to storage areas such as deep lakes or the ocean. The Indians would paddle their canoes very little and not very deeply if they were going in the direction of flow of dark so as not to slow it down. However, if they were traveling opposite the natural flow of dark, they would dig their paddles very deep and rapidly to assist the flow of dark to its ocean storage place.
Dark is faster than light. If you would open a drawer very slowly, you will notice that the light goes into the drawer. (You can see this happen.) You cannot see the dark leave the drawer. Continue to open the drawer and light will continue to enter the drawer; however, you will not see any dark leave the drawer. Therefore, dark is faster than light. Go into a closet, close the door, and turn off the dark sucker. Have a friend open the door about 1 inch. Your friend will not see any dark leave the closet, nor will you. Have your friend open the door until half the closet is dark and half is light. Since 2 objects cannot occupy the same space at the same time, and you do not feel any change in pressure, by compressing the dark, it is logical to assume that dark is faster than light.

One last proof.

What is a by-product of movement of dark? Heat. What is a by- product of dark suckers? Heat, again.

Therefore a dark sucker generates heat during its operation, sucking dark from the surrounding area.
https://astro.uni-bonn.de/~dfischer/dark_sucker_2.html

Comment: This doesn't answer my question: what would be the effects if light was the default, but there were many dark sources (sorry, light suckers) like a dark sun?  How would this affect human culture?

Comment: This should be made Community Wiki as it is not your own work. I know it is annoying, but you should really not get reputation from somebody else's work, and you should not have extra ability to edit somebody else's work just because you posted it. It is common community consensus that other's work should be made Community Wiki. Please do so.

Comment: No problem at all. I agree completely with the logic and axioms. done and done.

Comment: Your heading made me think of a plague of evil leeches.

Comment: What doesn't make you think of a plaque of evil leeches?

Comment: Probably a plague of evil leeches

Answer (score 0):

If there was something like a dark sun, our whole culture would change. During the day (which would now be dark due to the dark sun), we would be active, making us nocturnal organisms. During the night (which would be light because the dark sun is gone), we would be resting. Since we would be nocturnal and since many of the world's major religions and holidays have to do with the triumph of light over dark, good over evil, I would imagine a lot of that would change and we would be night-worshipping creatures. Also, the impulse that bad things come out to hunt at night, which is wired into all of us, would be probably be reversed. We would fear the light of the night rather than the dark of the day. (Hey, rhyme and alliteration in the same sentence!)

Comment: What if the night were still the dark one?  We would probably still prefer the light, unless we evolved to live in total darkness.  Any more details?

Comment: no, not much. great question though!

Answer (score 0):

We would be awake at "night". There would be no dark sun when woke up, and the moon would cast its shadow over our activities. There would be less push to invent light sources, why invent light when all you need to do is go in the basement? However, when we wanted to sleep, we'd open the blinds all the way, to get some of that relieving darkness. I don't think it would be too different from modern times, except less windows and more activity underground. It might prove disorienting though, if your main character crossed over to there from here.

Otherwise, it could be just like earth, except with darkness and light inverted. In a different realm, people could see by shadows, like we see by light. Maybe it's an alternate earth dimension.

Comment: Okay.  Any more details about specific culture?

Comment: I don't think too much would change, except possibly people worshipping darkness instead of light. _You are my darkness, my only darkness, you make me happy, when skies are bright. You'll never know dear, how much I love you. Please don't take my darkness away._

Comment: I'm not sure.  We'd still not be able to see in darkness or anything.  We'd still live in light.

Comment: @CHEESE Probably. But do not question the Mystics! Or song writers!